# Parsing JsonObject to List<Map<String, Object>> using Gson?

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to parse a string representation of a JSON object into a List of maps.
The json object will be structured something like the following:

```
[
 {       
  "first_name": "fname1",
  "last_name": "lname1"
 },
 {
  "first_name": "fname2",
   "last_name": "lname2"
 }
 .
 .
 .
]
```

The only thing that is known is the strings values (e.g "first_name", "last_name") **on runtime only**, therefore I cannot create any predefined classes (like usually used in fromJson() method).

I have tried to create the following function (after I saw some examples online) and it didn't work:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> fromJson(String jsonAsString) {
    final JsonElement jsonElement = this.jsonParser.parse(jsonAsString);

    List<Map<String, Object>> myList= new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Type listType = TypeToken.get(myList.getClass()).getType();
    myList= (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonElement, listType);

    return myList;
}
```

The result of this function is a list (length == 2 in the above case) but instead of 2 maps i'm getting 2 Objects.

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand your use of `TypeToken`.

The point of `TypeToken` is to capture parameterized type (such as `List<...>`) by creating anonymous class that extends generic supertype parameterized by the type you want to capture, using the following syntax:

```
new TypeToken<... type you want to capture ...>() {}.getType()
```

In your case it should be used as follows:

```
myList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonAsString, 
    new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use generics like that, at runtime `List<Map<String, Object>> myList` is the same as `List<Object> myList`.

You can try with an array of maps

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map[] x = new Map[0];
    Map[] fromJson = gson.fromJson("[\r\n" + 
            " {       \r\n" + 
            "  \"first_name\": \"fname1\",\r\n" + 
            "  \"last_name\": \"lname1\"\r\n" + 
            " },\r\n" + 
            " {\r\n" + 
            "  \"first_name\": \"fname2\",\r\n" + 
            "   \"last_name\": \"lname2\"\r\n" + 
            " }]",x.getClass());
```